# Are there RSS feeds for iOS apps' reviews on the app store?

Tags: iphone, ios, rss, app-store, review

I am interested in getting an RSS feed for new customer reviews for my app on the app store, does Apple provide an RSS feed for new app reviews?

Comment: I didn't see it on Apples RSS page http://www.apple.com/rss/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are indeed feeds of App Store reviews by country.

Here's an example from my app (Snapix): https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=471339479/sortBy=mostRecent/xml

Comment: Yes.. and FYI: be design it only goes back 10 pages worth. You have to database and store on your own going forward to get more.

Comment: Currently the version number is showing as 0, e.g. <im:version>0</im:version>. This started happening recently :-(

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Apple doesn't, but there are third parties that do. I use [AppComments](http://appcomments.com/)</strike>

Apple has since added an RSS feed, see Thundertron's answer below

Comment: Ok, so how does AppComments get the data then?

Comment: If you use a http sniffer such as HTTPScoop: http://www.tuffcode.com/, and then open up iTunes on your computer, you might be able to discover that Apple is using webpages in iTunes. With the right format, you can probably pull out the comments page and then parse it.

Comment: coneybeare: That was helpful!!! I wish apple or someone else could publish the raw feed itself where one can add some parameters and create the custom feed.