# How to get notified when your iOS app receives a new rating or comment

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to receive some sort of notification when my iOS app receives a new rating or comment in the AppStore.  The iTC Mobile app provides no means that I can find to receive notifications when a new rating is added.

For my Android apps, I use Andlytics which presents a notification anytime a new comment or rating is added - is there anything similar that anyone knows about for iOS?

I don't care if it's a push notification to my iPhone, an email, an SMS or something else - I'm just looking for a way to be notified when this event happens.

**Edit:**

I finally found the perfect solution: LaunchKit w/ slack integration. I get a message in slack every time a new iOS review shows up, and it's great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the mail that App Annie distributes daily to be a good compilation of sales data and user reviews.
http://www.appannie.com

Comment: Awesome - I can't believe I didn't know about this yet.  I just signed up and am already very impressed with the amount of data they provide...huge bonus that it's free.  Thanks!

Comment: Nowadays, I use LaunchKit with a hook to Slack, so I get a slack message every time a new review is written.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using https://appbot.co which sends daily emails with the reviews from all countries. Has been working great.

Answer (score 0):

One more great resource to get app status.
https://github.com/mattlawer/appstat.git

Look at the usage, its pretty cool. No need to register.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for using 3rd party services. Apple provides a RSS feed: [Are there RSS feeds for iOS apps' reviews on the app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891466/are-there-rss-feeds-for-ios-apps-reviews-on-the-app-store/14923036#14923036)

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign in to ["Connect" app from Apple](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/app-store-connect/id1234793120) on your iPad/iPhone
2. In "My Apps" section, select the app you want to be notified about reviews.
3. Go to "Notifications" section and tap on "mobile"
4. Select notifications for app reviews from 1 to 5 stars.
5. Now you will receive push notifications when new review will be added.

[Notifications for iOS App Store Reviews](https://imgur.com/a/dRLQvR9)